# Why does changing second state variable in React cause changes in first state variable to take effect?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I can't easily reproduce this in a shorter example, but my problem was this:

1. `section` is a JavaScript object that is part of state variable array of JavaScript objects which is in the **parent module**
2. I can successfully change the value of `section.showContent` when clicking on the button that calls `toggleContent()`, but this change would not have any effect on the page.
3. Only when I created **another state variable** and change the value of that state variable, does the change in `section.showContent` have an effect on the state on my page.

This happens to fix my current problem, but I have no idea why this works.

Can anyone explain it?

[image]

```
interface ICurriculumSectionProps {
    section: any;
    searchText: string;
    sectionIndex: number;
}

function CurriculumSection(props: ICurriculumSectionProps) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('start');
    const { section, searchText, sectionIndex } = props;
    const toggleContent = () => {
        section.showContent = !section.showContent;
        setMessage(`${message}n`); // necessary to make changes in section variable affect React page
    };
    return (

        <li id={section.isToday ? 'today' : ''} key={sectionIndex} className="section">
            {(section.formattedDay && (searchText.trim() === '' || (section.bulkSearchText.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase())))) && (
                <div className={section.isToday ? 'dayLabel isToday' : 'dayLabel isNotToday'}>
                    {section.formattedDay}
                </div>
            )}
```

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem)... you're mutating the state. Don't ever mutate state in React, else you'll encounter unexpected behavior like this

Comment: The component will re-render when its state is changed, not when it is mutated, even less when the props are mutated. Do you need the parent to know about changes in `showContent`?